# Memory leak in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

```
while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
//Expenseentry* temp=[[[Expenseentry alloc]init]autorelease];
//Expenseentry* temp=[[Expenseentry alloc]init];
            temp=nil;
            temp=[[Expenseentry alloc]init];
                        //memory leak here
            temp.ID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",primaryKey];
                        //memory leak here 
            int i=1;    
 @try{
//Expenseentry* temp=[[Expenseentry alloc]init];
//tried this but no luck
 NSString   *s=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 1)];
                        temp.amount=s;
                        [s release];
                        [arrreturn addObject:temp];
                        //[temp release];
//if i uncomment this app crashes 
                        //[formatter release];
                        //printf("\n daata count %d ",[arrreturn count]);
                    }
                    @catch(id ex )
                    {
                        printf("ooooopssss exception ");
                    }
                    i++;
            }
```

my expense entry class

```
@interface Expenseentry : NSObject {
    NSString *ID; 
    NSString *amount;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *amount;
@end
 and .m is just 
- (void)dealloc {
    [ID release];
[amount release]
}
```

Comment: You need to fix the code, as it is cut off, and you probably need a more detailed question, like where you think the leak could occur (trying using the Analyzer built into Xcode, Cmd+shift+A)

Comment: @jonathan code is fixed now. When I run this for first time it works but for second run it shows memory leak. and it is obvious cause as i havent released temp cause if i will app crashes

Comment: i have tested above code with instrument and written comment at statement just bellow where it shows memory leak

Comment: What object does instruments say is leaking? The entire Expenseentry? Try pressing ⌘+E in instruments to get the extended details view.

Comment: it indicates expenseentry as well as all its properties has leked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my mistake just posting if any one can explain this behavior:
memory leak cause array and array-object were not released.If I would release any of it app crashes.

mistake 1:[super dealloc] missing in expenseentry's dealloc.
doubt:**why is it required to release super?** when apple doc says you have to release object you own.

mistake 2:array being returned by this function is stored in instance variable(and synthesized property with retain as attribute) of caller.
and I have released that property in dealloc as it is retained.

```
receivedArr=fun()
```

in dealloc

```
[receivedArr release]
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It looks like temp is an instance variable for that class
2. Make sure you release temp when you are done or right before you use it again

Try doing the following

```
[temp release];
temp=[[Expenseentry alloc]init];
temp.ID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",primaryKey];
```

The other option is to release after your done with it inside of the while(sqlite3_step) loop

```
while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
...
temp=[[Expenseentry alloc]init];
temp.ID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",primaryKey];
... //Use temp
[temp release];
temp = nil; //Best practice to set it to nil
```

If the temp.ID string is leaking you need to look into the Expenseentry class to make sure your doing proper memory management there.

Edit: I now see the rest of your code posted

```
[arrreturn addObject:temp];
//[temp release];
//if i uncomment this app crashes
```

The reason why it is probably crashing is as I said before make sure you set it to nil after releasing

Edit 2: You are reusing the same object inside of the while loop also
You will want to move the temp allocation into the while loop or else every object in that array will point to the same object. I am not sure what you goal is with the code but take at a look at the following code.

```
while(i>5)
{
   temp=[[Expenseentry alloc]init];
   temp.ID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",primaryKey];
   @try
   {
      NSString   *s=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 1)];
                        temp.amount=s;
                        [s release];
                        [arrreturn addObject:temp];
   }
   @catch(id ex )
   {
      printf("ooooopssss exception ");
   }
   [temp release];
   temp = nil;
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Expenseentry is like a pojo in java which has just synthesized properties

Comment: i have already tried using local variable allocating at start in loop and release at end but that gave me memory leak  so i m trying reusing same pointer

Comment: The problem with that is when you add it to the array it will retain a pointer to the same Expenseentry. So each time you change temp.amount all of the objects in that array will have the same temp amount. Also it looks like your while loop is an infinite loop :) while(i > 5) i++;

Comment: ooooopsssss sory i dnt knw whts the prob but its actually while(i<col) but if i put "<" code get cutoff also i have edited to show relevent code only

Comment: Ok I would try my first example of releasing then setting to nil right after using the object. I expect then you will no longer have memory leaks but start to notice issues I addressed in Edit 2

Comment: @joe i culd nt observed behavior u r saying all expenseentry.amount has proper values

Answer (score 1):

the temp=nil seems a bit odd. whenever you assign the variable temp to a new object don't forget to release the previous object.

if you write:

```
Expenseentry* temp=[[Expenseentry alloc]init];
temp=nil;
```

you get a memory leak because you have created an Expenseentry object and then said good riddance to the object basically. You need to do a [temp release]; before assigning to nil on the iphone.

there could be other leaks like in your Expenseentry but you don't show how it looks like i.e. how the properties ID are declared.

Comment: I tried simply allocating at start and releasing at end in loop  but didnt work so i tried by doing it temp=nil

Comment: temp is local variable in function